Keep first K fields fixed but sum rest of fields between two files
Hi I have two files with the same number of columns and rows. The first 8 columns are identical.
file1:
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0.95    0.99    0.99    0.67
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0   0   0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0   0   0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0   0   0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0.05    0.01    0.01    0.33

file2:
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0.97    0.59    0.97    0.88
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0.02    0   0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0   0.02    0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0.02    0.02    0   0.11
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0.37    0   0.01

How to write a shell script to perform elementwise summation between the two files
starting from field 9 to the last column to get a result as the following:
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   1.92    1.58    1.96    1.55
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0.02    0   0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0   0.02    0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0.02    0.02    0   0.11
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0.05    0.38    0.01    0.34


Are the fields tab-separated? Should the result have the same field separator?

With perl in awk mode:
perl -lane '
  $_ = <STDIN>; @F2 = split;
  $F[$_] += $F2[$_] for 8 .. $#F;
  print join "\t", @F' file1 < file2

Here using any amount of whitespace as input field separator (and ignoring the leading and trailing ones) and TAB as output field separator. For TAB as both input and output field separator:
perl -F'\t' -lane '
  $_ = <STDIN>; chomp; @F2 = split "\t";
  $F[$_] += $F2[$_] for 8 .. $#F;
  print join "\t", @F' file1 < file2

Note the 8 instead of 9 as perl starts numbering its @rray elements from 0, not 1.
The awk equivalent would look like:
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
  {
    getline l2 < "file2"; split(l2, f2)
    for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) $i += f2[i]
    print
  }' file1


Nice shot sir ^^

Let awk read the two files pasted side by side:
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9+$17, $10+$18, $11+$19, $12+$20 }'
chr22 10550966 22:10550966:C:T C T . . . 0.95 0.99 0.99 0.67
chr22 10550966 22:10550966:C:T C T . . . 0 0 0 0
chr22 10550966 22:10550966:C:T C T . . . 0 0 0 0
chr22 10550966 22:10550966:C:T C T . . . 0 0 0 0
chr22 10550966 22:10550966:C:T C T . . . 0.05 0.01 0.01 0.33

If your input is tab-delimited and your output should be that too, then set FS = OFS = "\t" in the awk code:
$ paste file1 file2 | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9+$17, $10+$18, $11+$19, $12+$20 }'
chr22   10550966        22:10550966:C:T C       T       .       .       .       0.95    0.99    0.99 0.67
chr22   10550966        22:10550966:C:T C       T       .       .       .       0       0       0    0
chr22   10550966        22:10550966:C:T C       T       .       .       .       0       0       0    0
chr22   10550966        22:10550966:C:T C       T       .       .       .       0       0       0    0
chr22   10550966        22:10550966:C:T C       T       .       .       .       0.05    0.01    0.01 0.33


Using awk:
awk '
    BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
    NR==FNR{
        a[NR]["c09"]=$9
        a[NR]["c10"]=$10
        a[NR]["c11"]=$11
        next
    }
    {
        $9= a[FNR]["c09"] + $9
        $10=a[FNR]["c10"] + $10
        $11=a[FNR]["c11"] + $11
        print
    }
' file1 file2

chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   1.92    1.58    1.96    0.88
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0.02    0   0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0   0   0.02    0
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0.02    0.02    0   0.11
chr22   10550966    22:10550966:C:T C   T   .   .   .   0.05    0.38    0.01    0.01

